# loop to prevent application from closing

Tags: java, loops

How can I prevent my Application from closing?
I just open a few sockets via JNI, afterwards it closes my application.

Now I have started a Thread with an loop

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));
            String line = "";
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()).equals("exit")) {
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }).start();
```

This works fine, but is this the best(or at least a good) way to do this?

Comment: This kind of question is better ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Blocking on IO is the right thing to do in such cases. I see no problems.